# Convert base64 to text

Tags: java, internationalization, base64, hex

I'm working on application where I receive messages encoded to base64.
the messages can be received in all languages and can contains also just numbers. I need to convert the base64 into readable text.
to get the text.
I am using 
apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 and
apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

I have 2 problems:

1. when I'm trying to parse messages received in English or numbers
   I can't parse the base 64 correctly.
2. how can I  distinguish between base64 message which is represented by 4 digits of hex like Russian or Hebrew to message in English or numbers which is represented by 2 digits of hex like numbers or English.

here is my code:

```
private String convertBase64StringToText(String base64) {
    base64 = "MdmMBg==";//base64.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
    String basetohex = Hex.encodeHexString(decoded);
    char ch[] = basetohex.toCharArray();
    String output = new String(ch);
    output = output.toUpperCase();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i=i+2){

        str.append((char) Integer.parseInt(output.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
        //for languages like russian or hebrew i'm changing from 
         //output.substring(i, i + 2) to output.substring(i, i + 4) and it 
          //works fine

    }

    System.out.println("str.toString():"+str.toString());//received: 1Ù instead of 1234
    return str.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The below four utility methods help you to encode and decode to and from
>   Base64. Please try them I think your problem will solve as these methods use UTF-8 as their charset:

```
public static String encodeBase64(String plainText) {
    byte[] plainTextByteArray = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainTextByteArray);
    return base64Encoded;
}

public static String decodeBase64(String base64File) {
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64File);
    String decodedStr = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return decodedStr;
}

public static String encodeBase64(byte[] fileByteArray) {
    String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileByteArray);
    return base64Encoded;
}

public static byte[] decodeBase64ToByteArray(String base64File) {
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64File);
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: i've tried this: ` byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode("MdmMBg==");
        String decodedStr = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("decodedStr:"+decodedStr);` but received again:1ٌ

Comment: @HaimKlainman of course because you have to encode your String first before you decode it. The decoding only work after you encode it, not just decoding a normal String!!!! Try this:         String plainText = "MdmMBg==";
        byte[] plainTextByteArray = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String base64Encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainTextByteArray);

        byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(base64Encoded);
        String decodedStr = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("decodedStr:"+decodedStr);

Comment: Mehdi i'm not understand your exanmple and sorry for that but your last example returns the same base64 string :decodedStr:MdmMBg==

Comment: @HaimKlainman for decoding a value, you should encode first. In your previous comment you decoded a string without encoding it. This is wrong therefore it will not work

Comment: if i'm understand you correctly then even though i'm received the base64 string allready encoded to base64 and all i want is to decode it to readble string then i should first encode it again and then decode it as you showed in your first answer?

Answer (score 0):

The base64 encoding will apply to the binary form of the data that you have received.

Once you have the binary form, you will need to use the character encoding, e.g. UTF-8 (but it depends what was used originally) to convert the binary data to a Unicode string.

Once you have a Unicode string, it will be able to support all of the characters within the Unicode set. You won't have to worry whether they are Russian, Hebrew or any other type of characters.